# Playwright integration in Supabase Edge function

Tags: playwright, supabase-js, edge-function

Have anyone tried to integrate Playwright to a Supabase edge function and deployed it?
I am trying to do this integration  and deploy this as a supabase edge function.
There are documentations on integrating puppeteer.
But, There are no proper documentations around Playwright.
I have tried to integrate this and failed.
Can someone provide me a solution.

Any help is appreciated.